# Can not make ld find libraries

Tags: c++, linux, build, g++

I'm trying to build a package from source code on a Linux machine without sudo priviledge but the linker can't find the necessary library:

> ld: cannot find -lstdc++

I've found some solutions about this which involves reinstallation of the library but I can not follow without sudo.

`libstdc++.so.6` is present in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64` and the command `ld -lstdc++ --verbose` outputs:

```
......
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libstdc++.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libstdc++.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libstdc++.a failed
ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

So I made a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 ~/.local/lib/libstdc++.so
```

And then add the path to LIBRARY_PATH:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH='/home/xxx/.local/lib'
```

But the compiling just prints the same output (it did not search libraries in the added path). I've also tried these before compiling without success:

```
export LD_FLAGS='-L/home/xxx/.local/lib'
export LIBS='-lstdc++'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/xxx/.local/lib'
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what do I misunderstand here?

Comment: Fix the Linux machine's development configuration and environment, instead of trying to hack your way around it. If you don't have sudo privileges, that simply means that you cannot have a reasonable development environment on that machine. Find another machine, that's properly configured, to develop on.

Comment: Perhaps ask your sysadmin to run `ldconfig`. But Sam Varshavchik is really right.

Answer (score 0):

For which architecture are you compiling? 32 or 64 bit? Because you're on 64bit system, but linked 32bit variant, you need to double check.

What does 'ld -L/home/xxx/.local/lib --verbose -lstdc++' says?

BTW: better to ask admin of the machine to install development packages, you might even miss header files and others.